# Trying to use Pusher to read exchange data

Tags: javascript, ruby, http, pusher

I'm trying to read sell offers from this exchange called Liquid using Ruby's Pusher library. For some reason everything else in the documentation is in Ruby, except for the Pusher part which is in Javascript. [Link to the documentation](https://developers.liquid.com/?ruby#liquid-tap)

I read [Ruby's Pusher documentation](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-ruby#installation--configuration) and they simply don't really go well together. They don't use the same variables and I'm totally lost.

This is what I have so far and am kind of stuck. Even this is pretty much a guess.

```rb
require 'pusher'

taptoliq('price_ladders_cash_btcusd_sell')

def taptoliq(path=nil)
  channels_client = Pusher::Client.new(
      key: 'LIQUID',
      channel: path,
      event: 'updated',
      host: 'tap.liquid.com',
      wsHost: 'tap.liquid.com',
  )
PUSHER_URL = 'The example code doesnt have secrets, apps or app ids. The command below doesnt run without this being configured correctly.'

channels_client = Pusher::Client.from_env
end
```

I want to have a variable that would dynamically update. I'm not sure if my channel_client is configured correctly and I'm more than sure that PUSHER_URL is wrong as well. The final command of the function is what crashes complaining bad configurations. 
"Uncaught exception: C:/rubyproj/liquidtap.rb:10: dynamic constant assignment"

Answer (score 0):

The PUSHER_URL should not be defined in your code but as environment variable, as you assign this String to the constant, you get this error. It hould be in the form http://KEY:SECRET@HOST/apps/APP_ID

The .from_env reads this environment variable.

Environment variables are set differently depending in your operating system.